# How to get the expression that matched with regexps

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the expression that matched in a regexp, it's not clear so there is some code for you to understand:

```
while (something) {
    mymap[stmt.name] = {v : stmt.var}; //stmt.name is changing on each loop
    regexpString += stmt.name+"(.*)|";
}
regexpString = regexpString.slice(0, -1);
regexpE = new RegExp(regexpString, "i");
test = regexpE.exec(somevar);
```

Now, I want to get the `stmt.name` that match in order to get the element in the map, with `mymap[test]` or something like that.

Is there a way through it, or a better way that I didn't see ? I don't want to loop on each `stmt.name` each time, it will be heavy this way.

---

if my `regexpString` equals `http://foo.bar(.*)|https://bar.foo/foobar/(.*)` I want to be able to get `http://foo.bar` or `https://bar.foo/foobar/` according to my `somevar` variable

Comment: nope, it's not remotely clear...

Comment: share some inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: `$&` may be what you need, but it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Without knowing what your `stmt.name` looks like and what the final regex looks like, it's hard to tell. But, if you have multiple groups in your regex (because of the `()`), you should be able to tell which one matched by looking at the group indexes. For example `regexpE.exec(somevar)[1] !== undefined`

Comment: if my `regexpString` equals `http://foo.bar(.*)|https://bar.foo/foobar/(.*)` I want to be able to get `http://foo.bar` or `https://bar.foo/foobar/` according to my `somevar` variable

Answer (score 0):

Why not just capture it? Use

```
var names = [];
while (something) {
    mymap[stmt.name] = {v : stmt.var}; //stmt.name is changing on each loop
    names.push(stmt.name);
}
var regexpE = new RegExp("("+names.join("|")+")(.*)", "i");
var test = regexpE.exec(somevar);
var name = test[1],
    _var = mymap[name].v;
```

Comment: Because it will return the full capture, if my input is `http://foo.bar/bar/bar/bar`, it will return `http://foo.bar/bar/bar/bar` instead of `http://foo.bar/`
I also want to have some capture strings in my names.

So, I think it as to be a better way, for example, I want to be able having a name like that : `^https?://(foor|bar)\.(org|com)/`

Comment: It will return the full input in the first capture only if you have a `name` that will match the full input. Can you provide some example `stmt`s that are supposed to be looped?